# java.lang.NullPointerException AllSuggestionsActivity.onTextChanged (AllSuggestionsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);)

Tags: android

I am getting an error (`java.lang.NullPointerException`) when I execute the code for the `ListView` with `EditText` for filtering at the line

`AllSuggestionsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);`

kindly help.

```
public class AllSuggestionsActivity extends ListActivity {

    EditText inputSearch;
    ListView lstList;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> suggestionsList;

    // url to get all suggestions list
    private static String url_all_suggestions = "http://10.0.2.2/JKUAT-M-SUGGESTION-BOX/get_all_suggestions.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_SUGGESTIONS = "suggestions";
    private static final String TAG_SID = "sid";
    private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";

    // suggestions JSONArray
    JSONArray suggestions = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_suggestions);

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        lstList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);


        // Hashmap for ListView
        suggestionsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading suggestions in Background Thread
        new LoadAllSuggestions().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                AllSuggestionsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });


        // on seleting single suggestion
        // launching Edit Suggestion Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String sid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditSuggestionActivity.class);
                // sending sid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_SID, sid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Suggestion Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted suggestion
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all suggestion by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllSuggestions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllSuggestionsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading all suggestions. Please wait.......");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All suggestions from url
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_suggestions,
                    "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Suggestions: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // suggestions found
                    // Getting Array of Suggestions
                    suggestions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SUGGESTIONS);

                    // looping through All Suggestions
                    for (int i = 0; i < suggestions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = suggestions.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_SID);
                        String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_SID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        suggestionsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no suggestions found
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainScreenActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all suggestions
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllSuggestionsActivity.this, suggestionsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_SID,
                                    TAG_SUBJECT }, new int[] { R.id.sid,
                                    R.id.subject });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

xml code for the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">    

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="Search" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>-->

        <!-- Main ListView 
             Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
        -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    enter code here

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: onPostExecute(param) is invoked on the ui thread so there is no need for runonuithread. Also in your onPostExecute(param) you have ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(..) so your adapter is local to onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly find solution to the error:

```
public class AllSuggestionsActivity extends ListActivity {

SimpleAdapter adapter;

EditText inputSearch;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> suggestionsList;

// url to get all suggestions list
private static String url_all_suggestions = "http://10.0.2.2/JKUAT-M-SUGGESTION-BOX/get_all_suggestions.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_SUGGESTIONS = "suggestions";
private static final String TAG_SID = "sid";
private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";

// suggestions JSONArray
JSONArray suggestions = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_suggestions);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    suggestionsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading suggestions in Background Thread
    new LoadAllSuggestions().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single suggestion
    // launching Edit Suggestion Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String sid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditSuggestionActivity.class);
            // sending sid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_SID, sid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Suggestion Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted suggestion
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all suggestion by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllSuggestions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllSuggestionsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading all suggestions. Please wait.......");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All suggestions from url
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_suggestions,
                "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Suggestions: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // suggestions found
                // Getting Array of Suggestions
                suggestions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SUGGESTIONS);

                // looping through All Suggestions
                for (int i = 0; i < suggestions.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = suggestions.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_SID);
                    String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_SID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    suggestionsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no suggestions found
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainScreenActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all suggestions
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */

                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllSuggestionsActivity.this, suggestionsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_SID,
                                TAG_SUBJECT }, new int[] { R.id.sid,
                                R.id.subject });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                /**
                 * Enabling Search Filter
                 * */
                inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

                inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // When user changed the Text
                        AllSuggestionsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                            int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

xml file remains intact

Answer (score 0):

You've initialized your adapter to null & never re-initialized it with real values.  So when the line executes AllSuggestionsActivity.this.**adapter.getFilter()**.filter(cs) the part in bold is where the NullPointerException is being thrown.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
```

Also, it looks like your adapter depends on some JSON data, if thats the case & your trying to have filter options for that data, you could set the text watcher for your edit text in onPostExecute() after your adapter has the data ready.

Finally, you should get rid of runOnUiThread in your onPostExecute().  The onPostExecute() runs on the main UI thread by default so there is no need for runOnUiThread to be there.