# Searching with EditText

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

Can you help me with this. I want to create a search for my listview using editText. Everything is okay but when i run the application it causes a runtime error and i get the an NullPointerException on AlbumActivity.onTextChanged . Any idea how to solve this? Thanks. Here's the code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity{
ConnectionDetector cd;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;

JSONArray albums = null;    
EditText inputSearch;   
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;    

private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album.php";

private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_SONGS_COUNT = "songs_count";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
    getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());


    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        alert.showAlertDialog(AlbumsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);

        return;
    }


    albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                AlbumsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());  
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });

    new LoadAlbums().execute();


ListView lv = getListView();


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);


            String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);               

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });     
}


class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Listing Albums ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                params);


        Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

        try {               
            albums = new JSONArray(json);

            if (albums != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);


                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);


                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);


                    albumsList.add(map);
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
                        R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {
                                R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });


                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure - `activity_albums.xml` contains the `inputSearch` of type `EditText` ?

Comment: @Ved Prakash yes it contains ediText with an id of inputSEarch. It has error during runtime when i start typing what to search

Comment: Check all the values that you are passing for `onTextChanged` and make sure they are not null.

Comment: @Ved Prakash I guess the values im passing are null. I dont know how to fix that

Comment: Look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851134/java-lang-nullpointerexception-allsuggestionsactivity-ontextchanged-allsuggesti. See how the adapter is initialized in `onPostExecute()` and how the list adapter is set. You have to do like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter is not initialized. You make the following call :

```
AlbumsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
```

This won't work because your adapter is null. You call `setListAdapter` in `onPostExecute` but  that is a method of `ListActivity` that uses an internal adapter, it will not initialize your own member variable.

Instead, you could do this in onPostExecute :

```
AlbumsActivity.this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList, R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });
// updating listview
setListAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this.adapter);
```

Comment: it has an error - Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleAdapter to ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: Change the type of your adapter to SimpleAdapter, instead of ArrayAdapter<String>;

Comment: thanks its working. but if i type a number or digit. it duplicates the item being searched. why is that?

Comment: I don't know. What do you mean by "it duplicates the item" ?

Comment: I used a number to make a search because some the of items have number on their title on the list but it displays two or 3 item results with the same value.

Comment: It might be due to the fact that we use SimpleAdapter. This question using a custom adpater may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753829/listview-arrayadapter-filtering-duplicate-items. Please consider accepting the answer if it solves your NullPointerException issue (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks ;)